# Get http reponse body using pear in php code

Tags: php, http, pear

I want to get Httpresponse body in php.I have used pear.but it gives me blank page.
my code is

```
   require_once "HTTP/Request.php"; 
   $req =& new HTTP_Request("http://www.yahoo.com/"); 
   if (!PEAR::isError($req->sendRequest())) { 
       echo $req->getResponseBody(); 
   }
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use PEAR for this?  Why not cURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code itself seems correct. "Blank page" usually means that your script ends with a PHP error when `display_errors` is off. Look up the error log of your web server.

After you sort that out consider using [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2) instead.

Comment: i want to fetch raw http response body but the browser renders it so how can i do that with the code given below.<?php
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$request  = new HTTP_Request2('http://www.facebook.com/');
$response = $request->send();


echo "Response body:\n" . $response->getBody();
?>